# What is meant by the term "formal distance metric"?

Tags: distance-functions, metric

I am familiar with the idea of metrics in software and I know something about using distance functions in clustering, but I don't really know what is meant by "formal distance metric".  What is the difference between a distance function and a formal distance metric?

Comment: This needs more context for a good answer, but does this make sense: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Metric.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Distance.html. Here's an example of a metric that seems different than what we usually mean by distance: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaxicabMetric.html

Comment: Are you looking for the formal definitions of a metric and metric spaces? If yes, perhaps you should consider migrating this question to the math stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they probably meant is that it strictly meets the definition of a metric, as defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Definition). A function that is not non-negative would not pass muster, for example.

If this does not make sense, please cite the reference where you encountered the term.